# LDAP_SERVER_POLICY_HINTS_OID control not working in AD LDS Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: active-directory

I am attempting to get the "SetPassword" method of AD LDS to honor password history domain policies however it is allowing me to set the password even after using LDAP_SERVER_POLICY_HINTS_OID. Cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is the code:

```
public SetPasswordResult SetPasswordHonoringHistory ( FeiUser feiUser, string password )
    {
        if ( password == null )
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException ( "password" );
        }
        try
        {
            using (var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection( _identityProvider.LdapUrl ))
            {
                // enable Kerberos encryption
                ldapConnection.SessionOptions.Sealing = true;
                if ( !_identityProvider.LdapUseIntegratedCredentials )
                {
                    ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
                    ldapConnection.Credential = new NetworkCredential(
                        _identityProvider.LdapAdminUser, 
                        _identityProvider.LdapAdminPassword,
                        _identityProvider.Domain);
                }
                ldapConnection.Bind ();

                const string attribute = "unicodePwd";
                const string LDAP_SERVER_POLICY_HINTS_OID = "1.2.840.113556.1.4.2239";

                // modification control for the replace operation
                var attributeModification = new DirectoryAttributeModification
                {
                    Name = attribute
                };
                attributeModification.Add ( Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes ( String.Format ( "\"{0}\"", password ) ) );
                attributeModification.Operation = DirectoryAttributeOperation.Replace;

                var modifyRequest = new ModifyRequest ( feiUser.DistinguishedName, attributeModification );
                var passwordHistoryFlag = new DirectoryControl (
                    LDAP_SERVER_POLICY_HINTS_OID,
                    BerConverter.Encode ( "{i}", new object[] {0x1} ),
                    true,
                    true );
                modifyRequest.Controls.Add ( passwordHistoryFlag );

                try
                {
                    var result = ldapConnection.SendRequest(modifyRequest);
                    if ( result.ResultCode == ResultCode.Success )
                    {
                        return new SetPasswordResult ( true, true );
                    }
                }
                catch ( DirectoryOperationException exception )
                {
                    switch ( exception.Response.ResultCode )
                    {
                        case ResultCode.UnwillingToPerform:
                            return new SetPasswordResult ( true, false );
                        case ResultCode.ConstraintViolation:
                            return new SetPasswordResult ( false, true );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            Logger.Error ( e );
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also running into the same issue if I use the same OID as you. It is working if I use the deprecated OID, 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2066.

According to the reference link I provided, it is deprecated but can still support Windows Server 2008 R2, 2012, 2012 R2, and 2016 Technical Preview. It also mentioned the following:

> The LDAP_SERVER_POLICY_HINTS_DEPRECATED_OID control has the exact
>   semantics and behaviors as LDAP_SERVER_POLICY_HINTS_OID (section
>   3.1.1.3.4.1.27); this control MAY be used by clients when the server does not support LDAP_SERVER_POLICY_HINTS_OID. Clients SHOULD use
>   LDAP_SERVER_POLICY_HINTS_OID when it is supported by the server.

Reference Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223320.aspx